# Regex and Arabic "Tanwin"

Tags: regex, vb.net, arabic

I am trying to match words driven from a database in a string input using VB .NET
The syntax I am using is so simple:

```
Regex.Matches(ArticleBody, "\b" & TagLabel & "\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Where "TagLabel" is a variable from the database, and "ArticleBody" is the user input.
All is working fine, but I have a little issue:

Let's suppose that:

```
TagLabel = "مصر"
ArticleBody = "لكن الجنرال المدني مصرٌ على الأمل، ولو كان حزيران يشي بالعكس."
```

Please note the "Tanwin" in "مصر" in the ArticleBody " ٌ " at the end of the fourth word.
The Regex function is matching the word "مصر", while it should not.
I already searched for solutions, but didn't find any.

Please advise.

Comment: As I know, such characters (like "ً", "ٌ", "ٍ",...) are **NOT** considered as word characters!

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817203/php-regex-to-find-specific-arabic-keywords), it may help!

Comment: @Death Thank you for your comments, The second link didn't help alot, I tried to make it work for my case, but unfortunatily it didn't.

Comment: Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CategoryOrBlock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try:

```
Regex.Matches(ArticleBody, "\b" & TagLabel & "\b", 
  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
```

---

**Update:** Try this one:

```
Regex.Matches(ArticleBody, "(?<=(?:\s|^))" & TagLabel & "(?=(?:\s|$))", 
  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried that, and got the same result.